# como pongo una imagen sobre un contenedor que le he aplicado un clip path

Tags: html5, css3, imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A este contenedor le aplique un `clip path` justo como se ve en la imagen pero no me deja poner la imagen sobre ella, me la corta.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
```

Comment: prueba agregando la propiedad `z-index = 1000;` al imagen.

Comment: ya lo hice pero no me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar dos `div` uno para el contenido y otro para la imagen. A ambos le asignas la propiedad `position: absolute;` pero con `z-index` diferente... *Ajusta los tamaños a tu necesidad*.

Ejecuta el `snnipet` para que veas el resultado. *la imagen puede tomar un rato para mostrarse por ser un vínculo externo.*

```css
.base{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.overlap{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left : 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
</div>
<div class="overlap">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: gracias, DjCrazy